# Combine two array to given format in swift5

Tags: ios, swift

I have two arrays. 1 with names and another with emails with same count. I need a array given below. Can anyone help on this

```json
[
    { "name": "Test", "email": "test@gmail.com" },
    { "name": "Test Mail", "email": "test3@gmail.com" },
]
```

Comment: I only see one array of a dictionary.

Comment: @ElTomato I think he's describing his expected output

Comment: How do you get the two separate arrays of names and emails, and why are they separate to begin with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let names = ["Test", "Test Mail"]
let emails = ["test@gmail.com", "test3@gmail.com"]
let dict = zip(names, emails)
    .map { ["name" : $0, "email": $1] }

print(dict)
```

That outputs

```
[["name": "Test", "email": "test@gmail.com"], ["name": "Test Mail", "email": "test3@gmail.com"]]
```

(The inner structure is a dictionary. Swift's print statement displays dictionaries as `[key:value, key:value]` with square brackets. Curly braces is the way they appear in JSON.)

Comment: OP probably is asking how to convert those two arrays into that JSON string

Comment: Maybe the OP wants JSON output. If so, they need to say that.